# Search results xml, c # - Windows Application Store

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xaml, windows-store-apps

Good day, I am creating an app bible, I'm having trouble searching the verse ("v"). I have created the whole structure can filter the book ("b"), then it loads a list of all the chapters ("c"), when you select a chapter, it creates a list and loads all the verses. Now I want to put together a code so that when the user clicks on a list number, is displayed the text of this verse.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bible>
  <b n="Gênesis" indice="1">
    <c n="1">
      <v n="1">text text</v>
      <v n="2">text text text</v>
    </c>
    <c n="2">
      <v n="1">text text</v>
      <v n="2">text text text</v>
    </c>
  <b n="Êxodo" indice="2">
    <c n="1">
      <v n="1">text text</v>
      <v n="2">text text text</v>
    </c>
    <c n="2">
      <v n="1">text text</v>
      <v n="2">text text text</v>
    </c>
  </b>
</bible>
```

C#

```
private void listBoxTeste1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedindex = listBoxTeste1.SelectedIndex;

        //Carregar o arquivo xml
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("biblia.xml");


        var players = from player in xdoc.Descendants("v")
                      where (string)player.Attribute("n") == selectedindex.ToString()
                      select new
                      {
                          Versiculo = (string)player.Element("v")
                      };

        //listBox2.ItemsSource = players;
        nameInput.Text = nameInput.Text + "     " + players;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually not quite clear on the question, but since the code has some errors, I assume that's the thing you need help with;

```
var players = from player in xdoc.Descendants("c")
              where (string)player.Attribute("n") == 
                    selectedindex.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
              select new
              {
                  Versiculo = player.Elements("v").Select(x => x.Value)
              };

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", players.First().Versiculo));
```

`players` will return a collection of strings (the items inside the `v` nodes) in `Versiculo`, and just print them out joined by `,`.

The thing that made it return no results was that you're getting the first matching `v` node, then trying to take the `v` subnodes of it as a result.